# Best practice for angular2 component with arbitrary sensor data

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm trying out some angular2 concepts, and have hit the first bump on the road..

I have a websocket that pushes messages with sensor values. These values are in the form of a json object:

```ts
{
 "sensorId" : "1",
 "sensorType" : "2",
 "sensorValue" : "10.1"
}
```

As I have no control over when these come in, there is also a webservice, that can be used to query the last seen value from a particular sensor, this also returns an object like the above.

Now the question is, how should I use this in my angular component / services? I have a dashboard, where I want to show the individual sensor values, in different parts of a dashboard. I have made a sensor.component.ts like:

```ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Sensor } from './sensor';
import { SensorService } from './sensor.service';

@Component({
    selector : 'sensor',
    template : `
        <div class="sensor s{{size}}">
            <div class="value"><span>{{value|number : '1.2-2'}}</span></div>
            <div class="label">{{label}} ({{unit}})</div>
        </div>`
})

export class SensorComponent {
    @Input() id : number;
    @Input() type : number = 2;
    @Input() label : string = "N/A";
    @Input() size : number = 4;
    @Input() unit : string = "N/A";
    value : number = 0;
    errorMessage : any;
    _sensorService : SensorService;
    constructor (private sensorService : SensorService) {
        this._sensorService = sensorService;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._sensorService.getSensor(this.id, this.type).subscribe(val => this.value = val, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
}
```

And accompanying sensor.service.ts:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SensorService {
    private sensorUrl = "https://xxx/node/environment";
    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    getSensor(id:number, type:number) : Observable<number> {
        let url = this.sensorUrl + '?node=' + id.toString() + "&subType=" + type.toString();
        return this.http.get(url)
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res:Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || 0;
    }

    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
        let errMsg : string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err= body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }

        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

The above is only the webservice that I query, but I am uncertain if this is the correct method, that the service gets called multiple times on a page, requesting different sensors every time.

Also, how should I go ahead and add websocket listener, so I can get instant sensor values in my app?

Comment: If you want to display the value of N sensors, and you only have a web service allowing to get the value of 1 sensor, what other choice do you have than calling the service N times, once for each sensor? Regarding the code, don't use string concatenation, without any parameter encoding, to pass parameters. Use params.

Comment: in theory I can get an array containing any number of sensor values, if I call without parameters, I get the latest stored values from all sensors. I copied the code from an old project, where I just get one value at the time.. Also, this is meant for initialization at start of the app / dashboard, after initialization, a websocket connection should be established, which also publishes the data.

Comment: Then using that would make things more efficient, since you would use a single request instead of N. Whether that's important or not is up to you to decide.

Comment: But how would I go about that? Fetch the whole data, store it in an array inside the service, from which I serve the data?

And what about the websocket interface, that sends updates to the data? How can I push those changes upwards to the components?

Comment: No. I'd get the array of sensors and store this array from/in the component displaying the list of sensors, and pass each sensor to the sensor component using an input property. Regarding websockets, that is too broad. Read the documentation about websockets, and try something.

Comment: The sensor component is used in different parent components, the parent components are showing different sensors, and at same time..

The app is divided in to a "static" sensor display, showing inside / outside temperature and humidity. and a dynamic area (router outlet), that shows different sensor values depending on the route that you are at..